# Error: No module named [filename]

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku, module

I'm building a Django app and am in the process of migrating to Heroku and Heroku Postgres. When I run "python manage.py runserver" or even "heroku run python manage.py runserver" Terminal returns the error "Error: No module named filename" - with the filename being the app folder sitting inside my main project folder that contains my models.py and views.py files etc. Please see the file structure below.

I have the app folder listed in my INSTALLED APPS and it shows up when I run "ls" for projectname so I'm puzzled as to why it can't be found.

I have started a new app using startapp and moved the contents of the old one over just to see if it was an anomaly. This only seems to have happened since trying to get Heroku working.

Here's my file structure for this project:

```
projectname/
      manage.py
      requirements.txt
      Procfile
      projectname/
           templates/
           __init__.py
           settings.py
           urls.py
           wsgi.py
      filename/
           __init__.py
           admin.py
           models.py
           tests.py
           urls.py
           views.py
      static/
      venv/
```

I've been struggling with this for over a day now so any help on how to get past it would be much appreciated!

EDIT: Here are all the places where I have mentioned filename in my code:

- In admin.py as 'from projectname.filename.models import *'
- In projectname/urls.py under URLconf as include('filename.urls',
  'namespace=filename')
- In filename/urls.py as 'from filename import *' and under URLconf as 'urlpatterns = patterns('filename.views' ...)
- In views.py as 'from filename.models import *'

I have run 'heroku run python manage.py syncdb' in venv as well and it still returns the error "Error: No module named filename".

Comment: Where in your code do you do `import filename`? is it somewhere under `projectname`?

Comment: @favoretti I've added an edit to my question above listing where I import filename across my code. I'm not sure if I have imported filename under projectname. How can I check if I have done so? I hope the above edit helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this line

```
In admin.py as 'from projectname.filename.models import *'
```

is giving issues. The `projectname` part IMHO shouldn't be there, so the line should just read

```
from filename.models import *
```

**[edit]**

And, both `projectname` and `filename` should be in the `INSTALLED_APPS`.

And to explain more on my line of thinking. Your `projectname.filename` refers to the inner `projectname` folder, so I'm thinking that it's trying to find `projectname/projectname/filename.py` file that doesn't exist. Just adding `filename` to `INSTALLED_APPS` will make the scope globally available and hence can be referred to as-is.

Comment: Thanks! I think this has solved it! I'm now seeing a different error when I run 'heroku run python manage.py syncdb'. The error is: 
! Heroku client internal error.
! Search for help at: https://help.heroku.com
! Or report a bug at: https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues/new

    Error:       Operation timed out - connect(2) (Errno::ETIMEDOUT)"

So I'm guessing that means the previous error is solved. Now I've just got to figure out what is going wrong with Heroku.

Comment: This has probably something to do with heroku itself, not sure :)

Comment: Sadly the error 'No module name filename' has shown itself again when I run heroku run python manage.py syncdb. If it helps, I am also getting the error 
"ImproperlyConfigured at /     
settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details." even though I have supplied the ENGINE value in settings.py as 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2'. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the whole `DATABASES` var in your question, preserving formatting and omitting or replacing hostname/username/password?

Comment: I've managed to get past it! I had to start a new heroku project but it seems to have worked :) Thank you again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I have a routine I use to dump the entirety of the Django module paths. The `re.sub()s` are there just to shorten up some of the paths and make it easier to see what is where.

```
import sys, re, os

def ModuleList():
    ret = []
    dir_project = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))
    project_name = os.path.basename(dir_project)

    for k,v in sys.modules.items():

        x = str(v)
        if 'built-in' in x:
            ret.append((k, 'built-in'))
            continue

        m = re.search(r"^.*?'(?P<module>.*?)' from '(?P<file>.*?)'.*$", x)
        if m:
            d = m.groupdict()
            f = d['file']
            f = re.sub(r'/usr/local/lib/python[.0-9]*/site-packages/django/', 'system django >> ', f)
            f = re.sub(r'/usr/local/lib/python[.0-9]*/site-packages/', 'site-packages >> ', f)
            f = re.sub(r'/usr/local/lib/python[.0-9]*/', 'python >> ', f)
            f = re.sub(dir_project+'.*django/', 'local django >> ', f)
            f = re.sub(dir_project+r'(/\.\./)?', project_name + ' >> ', f)
            ret.append((d['module'], f))
    ret.sort( lambda a,b: cmp(a[0].lower(), b[0].lower()) )
    return ret
# ModuleList

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for x in ModuleList():
        print "%s\t%s" % (x[0], x[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you in /venv?  I've run into similar errors after forgetting to enter the virtual environment.  To do so from the terminal, try:

`$ source venv/bin/activate`

Comment: I run into the same error when I am in venv. I have just run $ source venv/bin/activate and then heroku run python manage.py syncdb and Terminal returns "Error: No module named filename". Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like favoretti figured it out.  Good luck with the project!

Comment: Thanks! Now wrestling with Heroku errors but one step closer :)